# work out time difference between value 1st seen and last seen mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have had a look and although there have been question similar none have quiet helped towards my end goal so im hoping somebody could shed some light for me

I have a table and i would like to work out the time difference between when a value 1st come in and when its last seen however my issue is the value comes in and out the table several time throughout a day e.g.

```
| beacon | location | mac | date | time     |
|--------|----------|-----|------|----------|
| 53     | blue     | mac | date | 10:28:37 |
| 53     | blue     | mac | date | 10:28:48 |
| 53     | blue     | mac | date | 10:28:53 |
| 53     | blue     | mac | date | 14:02:12 |
| 53     | blue     | mac | date | 14:03:37 |
| 53     | blue     | mac | date | 14:03:58 |
```

in real terms its alot more data I want work out the time difference between 1st seen Figure A  and last seen figure B

max time difference would probably half hour so I had an idea of doing

```
select*,timediff() from table where time > now() - interval 30 minute
```

but not sure on what variable to use in timediff

or the other idea i had was to do number linked to colour(location) add a start time and when that stops being linked e.g. number is no longer picked up with colour add an end time

[Mysql Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ec2nz.png)

thank you for reading hoping someone can help haha

EDIT: Thank you all for your suggestion i will give them a try sorry i have not been very clear in my question my the database is to know how long a beacon ( the number) is seen for in a table however my issue is that the same beacon comes into the table several times throughout the day so its a case of beacon has been seen log time beacon is no longer seen in say a half hour period stop logging time I hope that makes more sense Thank you

Comment: Your question is not very clear regarding what you want to fetch from database. I mean that you probably want to fetch data per date and per beacon. So basically you should use `GROUP BY` on those two fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the below query as an example, some minor modifications may be needed.

```
SELECT *, 
MAX(`time`) AS `maxtime`,
MIN(`time`) AS `mintime`,
TIMEDIFF(MAX(`time`),MIN(`time`)) AS `timediff`
FROM `test` GROUP BY `beacon`,`date`
HAVING TIMEDIFF(`maxtime`,`mintime`)>=0
ORDER BY `timediff` DESC;
```

You can check the results on [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4db46/8).

Comment: This works a treat Thank you is there a way that i can limit it to a time interval such as

    SELECT *, 
    MAX(time) AS maxtime,
    MIN(time) AS mintime,
    TIMEDIFF(MAX(time),MIN(time)) AS timediff
    FROM osm where time > now() - interval 20 minute group by mac
    HAVING TIMEDIFF(maxtime,mintime)>=0
    ORDER BY timediff DESC;

Comment: @AvalonParkes-barton i am glad it helped you, for what you need you could simply use `CURRENT_TIME()` and `SUBTIME()` from MYSQL's date and time functions. Take a look in the revised SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4db46/16 i had prepared for you based on your data. In the lower 2 lines you will find the syntax for what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `min` and `max` functions to determine the values for the [`timediff`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff).

For example:

```
select *, timediff(max(time),min(time)) from table where time > now() - interval 30 minute
```

It may be more meaningful for you to include some grouping, as well. For example, if you want to find the timediff per location, you could group by that column. I've expanded the query to make it more readable:

```
select 
    location, 
    timediff(max(time), min(time)) 
from 
    table
where 
    time > now() - interval 30 minute 
group by 
    location
```

Comment: wouldn't you have to group by beacon in any case?

Comment: @ulferts I had a little trouble understanding the question, so I may have missed something. Can you clarify why it should be grouped by beacon? Generally speaking, min and max will be determined from the query results; so if there is no grouping, as in the first query, then every row will have the same timediff value of the absolute earliest and latest time returned in the query results.

Comment: had the same problem understanding the question so I am not 100% sure but as the column is called `beacon'  and OP wants to know when 'value 1st come in and when its last seen', I assumed it would make sense to group by that column. OP will probably know...